# LXDE: Add shell scripts, etc. to Run (Alt+F2) box

Tags: lxde

Is it possible to run one's own items from the Run box triggered by Alt+F2 in LXDE (ie lxpanelctl run)? For example, can I add shell scripts that I have created, so that they can be run from the Run box? If so, how can I do it?

I can run scripts I've created directly from a terminal and have them in a directory which has been added to $PATH but I don't know how to make them accessible via the Run box.

Comment: This is also discussed at https://sourceforge.net/p/lxde/bugs/919/

Answer (score 0):

If they are in your $PATH, and executable they will show up in `lxpanelctl run`

That is to say they do for me when running LXDE on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it isn't enough for me. I assume the one I'm using as a test is correctly in $PATH and executable because I can enter its name directly in a terminal and it runs fine. Entering it in lxpanelctl run gives me a 'failed to execute child process'. I'm on Arch so maybe I should ask in their forum :)

Comment: yeah maybe.  trying to think of LXDE-specific packages I might have that you do not.  Issue with that is I was testing your issue on a VM that will be used to roll out some kiosk-type stations and I decided to use LXDE because it's so lightweight.  I only installed `lxde lxdm` with the `--no-install-recommends` flag and I still get auto-completion.  And this is having started with the ubuntu server iso (i.e. no desktop).  Maybe the bash-completion package is stepping in to help out?

Comment: ooh.  it may be an issue on which dotfiles get sourced when you login.  I was just dealing with this earlier with Linux Mint 18.  When I login via GUI my `.bashrc` gets sourced, but from a terminal emulator it does not and it was causing issues with with my `$PATH`.   It came down to the GUI using `.profile` while my terminal emulator using `.bash_profile`, one of which wasn't sourcing `.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks for your further comments! I don't have .profile, and .bash_profile only has one line ([[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc). This problem has been solved here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1720408 but not in a very satisfying way so I'll hold off on creating a new answer. If you understand how I should be doing this right (adding ~/bin to $PATH such that LXDM sources it) then by all means update your answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: For me, running `PATH=~/.local/bin lxpanelctl run` in a terminal still doesn't find executables in `~/.local/bin`.