# Allowing scripts to be call by 'Run Command' dialog (Alt+F2)

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, gnome, run-dialog

Similar as [asked here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/369878/364080), I've been trying to understand how to include some paths to be reached during *Run command* dialog search in a GNOME environment.

In my `~/.bashrc` I've add some directories in my `PATH` and consequently I'm able to run some scripts they contain through an interactive shell section. However it's not enough to run them in *Run command* dialog.

How could I set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `PATH` variable is a solution, however, you set it in the wrong place. I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix) thread. The `~/.bashrc` file is loaded only when bash is started. You're probably looking for `~/.profile` or `~/.xprofile`. Depends on your system configuration.

Another solution would be creating a symlink to your executable file in one of the directories already present in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Pretty nice, Blue! The (linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962251/2989289) clarified a lot my doubts

Answer (score 0):

The run dialog will not read `~/.bashrc`. And that is not where it should be. It should be in `~/.profile`. And I would think that will work.

Comment: Well, my `~/.profile` `source`s my `~/.bashrc`, but the desired scripts still not found by *run command* dialog. I just made some tests managing `PATH` in `~/.profile` but without success, so I suppose there's something more required